# Azure Bot service for B2B

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

We are planning to develop a scheduling assistant bot. Could you please confirm if the below the scenario is possible?

`O365 Tenant1`user1@abc.com
`O365 Tenant2`user2@def.com
`O365 Tenant3`user3@ghi.com

user1@abc.com should be able to get the available calendar slots from user2@def.com & user3@ghi.com and block the calendar. The same thing should happen with other tenants also. Its basically a B2B collaboration.
If this scenario is not possible, what are the other possible solutions?

Thanks,
Madhan

Comment: Are all of the tenants in the same organization?

Comment: No they are from different organizations

Comment: Since all three tenants are not in the same organization, I don't believe this is possible. You could send calendar invites, but the user's would have to accept them and them to their calendar themselves.